# Universal Collection for both List and Map?

Tags: java, list, collections, types, dictionary

Is there a universal Collection I can use for both List and Map parameters, with the purpose of just checking not-null and size?

Right now I have a Validation class with the following method:

```
// Check if the given List is not null, nor empty
public static <E> boolean listNotNull(List<E> l, boolean checkSize, int size)
{
    // List is null: return false
    if(l == null)
        return false;

    // List is smaller or equal to given size: return false
    if(checkSize && l.size() <= size)
        return false;

    // Everything is OK: return true
    return true;
}
```

Which I can then use like this:

```
if(V.listNotNull(myList, true, 0)){ // if(myList != null && myList.size() > 0){
    // myList is not null, nor empty:
    ...
}
```

or

```
if(V.listNotNull(myList, true, 1)){ // if(myList != null && myList.size() > 1){
    // myList is not null, and has at least 2 items:
    ...
}
```

or

```
if(V.listNotNull(myList, false, 0)){ // if(myList != null){
    // myList is not null, but might still be empty:
    ...
}
```

I use this universal validation method for my Lists, but in one method I use a HashMap. With this HashMap I again want to check the same (not null, nor empty):

```
if(myHashMap != null && myHashMap.size() > 0){
    // myHashMap is not null, nor empty:
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to replace `List<E>` in my validation method's parameter with something else (like `Collection<???>`), so I include both Lists and Maps?

Or should I make a new method that does exactly the same, but instead of a List I use a Map as parameter, like so:

```
// Check if the given Map is not null, nor empty
public static <K, E> boolean mapNotNull(Map<K, E> m, boolean checkSize, int size)
{
    // Map is null: return false
    if(m == null)
        return false;

    // Map is smaller or equal to given size: return false
    if(checkSize && m.size() <= size)
        return false;

    // Everything is OK: return true
    return true;
}
```

and

```
if(V.mapNotNull(myHashMap, true, 0)){ // if(myHashMap != null && myHashMap.size() > 0){
    // myHashMap is not null, nor empty
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such interface or superclass. The null check can be done based on Object of course. But there is no common interface with the size method or similar.

Comment: Ok, so I have no other choice than to use two separated methods? Edit: Ment as response to: "Map is not a subinterface of Collection".

Comment: either that or use instanceof and cast. (which wouldnt be typesafe x.x)

Comment: Yes you have to code it twice. You could put it in one method taking an Object parameter and then typecheck and cast in the method, but I wouldn't recommend that. Just use two methods.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You can use the same name for both method, though. Java should be able to work out which method to use.

Comment: @tobias_k True, but if I use two separate methods anyway for List and Map, I might as well call them listNotNull and mapNotNull. Then it's also for better readability when I the methods in my code.

Comment: Another option is to pass the entry set of the map, which IS a `Collection`

Comment: @Ordous `myHashMap.entrySet()` would cause a NullPointerException when I use that as parameter when myHashMap is null, so that isn't really an option. I think I'll just stick with two methods.